# additive restore for rsync?

Tags: rsync

I have a directory backed up that I would like to do an additive restore from. What I mean is that I would like it to only copy those files which do not exist at all in the destination directory. I don't want it to update files that differ between the two directory.

I tried `--dry-run` commands without delete options, but it still proposed updating existing files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-u if your timestamps are correct and you want to update if source has newer modifications or --skip-existing if you don't want any updates.